# Javascript multiple assignment to test variable existance: var obj = obj = obj || {}

Tags: javascript, namespaces, overriding, variable-assignment

In Ady Osmani's [blog post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) about namespacing in js, he mentions 5 common practices to test existance of previously defined namepsace/object to prevent overriding. I copy here the 3 of my concern:

```
var myApplication = myApplication || {}; // option 1
...
var myApplication = myApplication = myApplication || {}; // option 3
myApplication || (myApplication = {}); // option 4
```

According to him, option 3 is better than option 1, but I can't see the difference between the 2. What is the upside of doing one more assignment?

Also why is option 4 considered the best-practice?

Comment: *"why is option 4 considered the best-practice?"* It is ? Source ?

Comment: Option 3 is redundant. There's no reason it's better than option 1.

Comment: I quote `however Options 3 and 5 may be considered more thorough`. There doesn't seem to be any elaboration, just an opinion.

Comment: Option 3 is horrible IMO...Option 4 is basically `if(!myApplication) { myApplication = {}; }` In the end it is someone's opinion for "best"

Comment: @dystroy the same page from where OP got those samples is the one saying option 4 is best practice. I don't know if it really is, though, so I am not backing the author's opinion.

Comment: Option 4 is the *least* safe one. It will throw an error if `myApplication` doesn't exist.

Comment: Can we simply agree here that the first option is a frequent and correct practice while the other ones are bad ?

Comment: @dystroy that's my vote :)  That article is from 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any option without a `var` declaration is going to cause an exception in "strict" mode (or, as was pointed out in a comment, if you're **not** in "strict" mode!).  Thus, option 4, as written, is not an option.

Option 3 is not different than option 1 in any way.  Option 1 is effectively the same as

```
var whatever;
whatever = whatever || {};
```

Option 3 is effectively:

```
var whatever;
whatever = whatever || {};
whatever = whatever;
```

The `var` declaration (*not* the initializing assignment) in all cases is treated as if it appears at the beginning of the scope (in this context, a script unit). If the symbol is already declared (already a property of `window`), then the `var` declaration has no effect.

Because of that, the `var` declaration is crucial. Because it's hoisted to the top of the code, the initialization expressions won't cause a "ReferenceError" in the case when "whatever" is *not* already defined.  Because the `var` takes care of the declaration in a non-destructive way, it's OK to refer to the symbol on the right side of the `=` operator.

Comment: It'll cause a ReferenceError even if it's not in strict mode.

Comment: @BlueSkies oh and that reminds me of a thing I wanted to include in the answer but completely forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Option 4 doesn't do any assignment if the variable is already assigned. The other options assign the variable to itself if it's already assigned, so they do an unnecessary assignment in that case.

I can't see how option 3 is better than 1.

Answer (score -1):

Option 4 is simply a shortcut for

```
if (!myApplication)
    myApplication = {};
```

**I would consider it the best, because it doesn't do any unnecessary assignments.**

Option 3 looks a bit silly to me, actually.

---

When stating I would consider it the *best* (read: most readable) solution, I was thinking about something like this:

```
function foo(bar) {
    bar || (bar = {});
}
```

Even though I would probably go even another way:

```
function foo(bar) {
    ((typeof bar) === 'object') || (bar = {});
}
```

Comment: I forgot the sentence why I would consider it the best option :p

Comment: BTW, this is the blog's option 2, which the OP didn't quote.

Comment: Your "best"  will throw an error if `myApplication` wasn't previously declared.

Comment: It'd work fine if you just added a `var myApplication;` statement before the `if`.